# Best practice when dealing with C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I would like to know in the below scenario, which practice would be right/ideal and if there are any other options I have.

Assume I have a class being inherited from another class.

```
class A { };

class B : public A { };

class C : public A { };
```

I maintain a map of A pointers (base class). These are actually either derived class B or class C.

Now, say I would like to do an operation x on one of the derived class pointers in the map. I see there are two ways of doing it.

1] Typecast the base class into dervied class and do the operation on it. Is this a good practice ?

2] Have a virtual function available in base class, so that you can do the operation without a typecast. The problem here I feel is that some of the methods might truly belong to the derived class, rather than with the base class. I mean, one method applicable to derived class B may not be applicable to derived class C. It makes me uncomfortable to have a pure virtual function on A. Having a pure virtual, is this a good practice ? Alternatively what can be done ?

Comment: 1] `dynamic_cast` and test. 2] opinion based. [0] _"... best practice..."_ option based.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having a pure virtual member function in a class.

Comment: @Deep I think, if you want to use virtual functions without a type cast, please make `interface`. And [1] is a good practice may be.

Comment: This is a design question and depends on the specific case, and sometimes on business requirements and maybe even personal preference. I'm not sure this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: i think the whole situation is design flaw. (1) You store map of base class pointers mean you do not need to know implementation details, just interface. (2) You want perform on implementation specific operation on base class pointer means you need to know implementation details. Which one is the case ?

Comment: @Ron what if the virtual member doesn't apply to all the derived classes ? If we take the traditional inheritance example, a class student and class employee inherits from class person. Many fields such as age, name, place are applicable to both student and employee. But salary, it is applicable only to employee. Assuming a getMethod for salary. Is it a good one to have a pure virtual function getSalary() in class person ?

Comment: @AndrewKashpur Thanks for the feedback. The reason they are maintained in a same map is that they all are essentially the same. If we maintain them separate, then there is no point in inheriting them. After the base class pointer to be acted upon is identified, it is time to take one step forward and act on it. That is where I need to know what I am dealing with. Do you think of an alternative ?

Comment: @Deep then you need an additional level of abstraction. Person is an interface and Employee inherits from Person but is itself another interface exposing getSalary etc..

Comment: @Deep about your answer to AndrewKashpur: there is still point in inheriting those, because they do model the same thing (a person). Now it gives me the hint you need a Visitor Pattern to model your problem, the interface inheritance is just ok. You don't feel confortable (I guess) because it doesn't fit the problem you're trying to solve, but the patterns comes just to help you to do that.

Comment: @Deep Cola and gazoline are essentialy liquids. So you put both cola and gazoline into bottles. then you put all bottles in one box. next you iterate through the box, and if it is cola you drink it, if its gazoline you put it into your car. But is it really good idea to store all bottles in the same box ? The thing is, if derived classes were really essentialy the same, pointer to base class would be enough. But since pointer to base class is not enough, they are not essentialy the same.

Comment: @moia and Andrew I am convinced by both of your explanation. Will re-think abt my design.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual functions were specially designed to work via pointers to the base class with objects of based or derived. Thus you'll get run time polymorphism, if all you classes support operation x().

However, if, say, only C supports x(), what behaviour you want for pointers to objects A and B? May be just store a range of pointers to C separately? You do not need inheritance in this case.

Either you can specify some empty implementation for x() in class A - which can be abstract if you do not need objects of class A. This is a usual practice.

Run-time casting has time cost and also involves if- check which has performance overhead.